# Solenoid for opening door latch

Tags: solenoid, latch

I would like to open a door latch with solenoid using a IR reciever (basically remote control).

My questions are as follows:

- What kind of signal (AC/DC) will I require through the solenoid?
- Is it possible to open the door using off the shelf solenoids (I don't have much experience in electronics)?
- Where can I get them and is it possible to repel/attract by changing their polarity?

Edit: I just need movement in one axis: left to right and right to left.

This is the type of door latch I'm using:

[image: Door Latch]

Comment: I think it will be easier to use a purpose-designed door solenoid. That simple door latch you show requires two movements (up and to the right) and can require a large force when it is not properly aligned (that is: after a while, just when you started to trust its smooth working).

Comment: This is really a mechanical question.  Solenoids are electrically-controlled linear acuators.  They are available in both push or pull configuration, and of course those can be flipped depending on the external mechanical setup.  They are also available in wide range of currents, voltages, travel distance, and force.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: Please see my edit.

Comment: @Prabhpreet You could buy ready made electronic door latches (hell, home depot has them). You could also use a run of the mill car door lock solenoid. 12v DC/Gnd one way opens it, the other way closes it. But you might be better off on DIY.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @kaz you need to flag for a moderator to have something migrated. Reopening it will not make it any more or less possible. Moderators review all but questions being sent to meta/SU.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a motor to slide the latch instead? (actuator)

[image]

It should have enough torque to move the latch left and right. Possibly different types will have various maximum lengths.

You will need a constant power source on a relay that is switched by your controller. It depends what you are using. Arduino? or some pre built IR receiver that has I/O available. There is not enough information on what you want to use to answer that properly.

There are solenoids specially build for door.

[image]

And again. This particular one is driven by 12volts so you would have to have a constant supply switched by a relay or two. One for forward/open the other for reverse/close.

You will have to shop around your self and do some more research in how you are going to control it all. Then when you got some better idea come back and ask a more specific question if you run into trouble.  There seem to be many tutorials on the web about this sort of thing.